# Firebase UpdateChildValues doesn't set any value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a chat app where the users could set 1:1 or 1:many chats rooms. I want to store all `uid`s for that `chat_room` under `chat_room_members`. I'm trying to use `updateChildValues([user.id: true])` but it's not setting anything. If I use `setValues` instead, it overwrites the `uid`s and stores just the last one, which is not what I want. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
// chat_room_members > chatId > userId : true
for user in recipients {
print("user id to be set in chat_room_members:", user.id) // prints successfully all uids of the users

    Database.database().reference().child("chat_room_members").child(chatId).updateChildValues([user.id : true])
}
```

PS: `recipients` is an array that stores all the users that the current user wants to start a chat with.

I'm testing this when the `chat_room_members` doesn't even exist on the database yet. The very first `chat_room` sets this node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var dic = [String:Bool]()
recipients.forEach { dic.updateValue(true, forKey:$0.id) }
Database.database().reference().child("chat_room_members").child(chatId).setValue(dic)
```

Comment: This works, but there's no `user`, only `id`, and if I use `[$0.id : true]` it sets the dictionary with a number in front. Ie `0` > `userId: true`

Comment: Excellent. That works. Thank you! But maybe add some explanation so that people can understand what is happening and why.

Comment: Great work solving the problem @Sh_Khan. Is there any reason this wouldn't also work with `updateChildValues` (since that's what OP uses)?